# accessor = undefined slows down the table

Tags: react-table, react-table-v7

I use react-table v7. During the table layout process, I noticed that the component rendering speed drops if the accessor returns undefined.
For example.

```
const data = {
  person: {
    name: 'Ann',
    age: 12,
  },
};

const columnFast = [
  {
    Header: 'Name',
    Cell: ({ value }) => <p>{value}</p>,
    minWidth: 150,
    Filter: DefaultColumnFilterArray,
    accessor: 'person.name',
  },
];

const columnSlowly = [
  {
    Header: 'height',
    Cell: ({ value }) => <p>{value ? value : 'no height'}</p>,
    minWidth: 150,
    Filter: DefaultColumnFilterArray,
    accessor: 'person.height',
  },
];
```

The example is far-fetched, but it reflects the essence of the problem.
Tell me what is the reason for the slowdown of the table in this case.

Comment: How did you measure the slowdown? How many rows does your table have? Why do you (want to) access a property that doesn't exist?

Comment: @knittl The speed was measured using a profiler, the table has about 5000 rows, I don't have a goal to access a non-existent property. I just noticed it.

Comment: Maybe open a bug with the authors of the table? (on GitHub)